# Singleton scopes in Dagger 2

Tags: dagger-2

I am trying to set up the following in Dagger 2:
An `EventFinder` has two parts: a `TriggerFinder` and an `ArgFinder` each of which have many different implementations which are themselves complex objects with many dependencies.  The code sample below successfully builds an `EventFinder` with sample `TriggerFinder` and `ArgFinder` which both depend on another object, `WordNet`.  However, `WordNet` is a very big, expensive, constant object I would like to share between models as a singleton.  The current implementation of `WithWordNetEventFinderComponent` loads up `WordNet` twice.  If I try marking the `@Provides` method in `WordNetModule` as `@Singleton`, I get the error:

```
Error: ArgFinderUsingWordNetComponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:
      @Singleton @Provides WordNet WordNetModule.provideWordNet()
```

But propagating `@Singleton` annotations up the tree of components only results in other errors.  What if the correct way to do this?

Full code:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import dagger.Component;
import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;

// WordNet - this is the expensive shared resource we would
// like to make a singleton
class WordNet {
  final String path;

  public WordNet(@Named("path") String path) {
    System.out.println("Loading Fake wordnet from " + path);
    this.path = path;
  }
}

@Module
class WordNetModule {
  final String path;

  public WordNetModule(String path) {
    this.path = path;
  }

  // uncommenting the line below causes errors
  //@Singleton
  @Provides
  public WordNet provideWordNet() {
    return new WordNet(path);
  }
}

interface TriggerFinder {

}

class TriggerFinderUsingWordnet implements TriggerFinder {
  WordNet wordNet;

  @Inject
  public TriggerFinderUsingWordnet(WordNet wordNet) {
    this.wordNet = wordNet;
  }
}

@Module(includes = WordNetModule.class)
class TriggerFinderWithWordnetModule {    
  @Provides
  public TriggerFinder provideTriggerFinder(TriggerFinderUsingWordnet triggerFinder) {
    return triggerFinder;
  }
}

interface ArgFinder {

}


class ArgFinderUsingWordnet implements ArgFinder {

  WordNet wordNet;

  @Inject
  public ArgFinderUsingWordnet(WordNet fakeWordNet) {
    this.wordNet = fakeWordNet;
  }
}
@Module(includes = WordNetModule.class)
class ArgFinderWithWordNetModule {

  @Provides
  public ArgFinder provideArgFinder(ArgFinderUsingWordnet argFinder) {
    return argFinder;
  }
}

// the composite object we wish to create
class EventFinder {

  private final TriggerFinder triggerFinder;
  private final ArgFinder argFinder;

  @Inject
  public EventFinder(TriggerFinder triggerFinder, ArgFinder argFinder) {
    this.triggerFinder = triggerFinder;
    this.argFinder = argFinder;
  }
}

// components to wire everything together
interface ArgFinderComponent {    
  ArgFinder argFinder();
}

interface TriggerFinderComponent {
  TriggerFinder triggerFinder();
}

@Component(modules = ArgFinderWithWordNetModule.class)
interface ArgFinderUsingWordNetComponent extends ArgFinderComponent {

}

@Component(modules = TriggerFinderWithWordnetModule.class)
interface TriggerFinderUsingWordNetComponent extends TriggerFinderComponent {

}

interface EventFinderComponent {
  EventFinder eventFinder();
}


@Component(dependencies = {ArgFinderUsingWordNetComponent.class,
    TriggerFinderUsingWordNetComponent.class})
interface WithWordNetEventFinderComponent extends EventFinderComponent {

}

public class DaggerComponentTest {
  @Test
  public void withWordNetTest() {
    final WordNetModule wordNetModule = new WordNetModule("myPath");

    DaggerWithWordNetEventFinderComponent.builder()
        .argFinderUsingWordNetComponent(
            DaggerArgFinderUsingWordNetComponent.builder().wordNetModule(wordNetModule).build())
        .triggerFinderUsingWordNetComponent(
            DaggerTriggerFinderUsingWordNetComponent.builder().wordNetModule(wordNetModule).build())
        .build().eventFinder();
  }
}
```

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/107).

Comment: @nhaarman: Thanks, that definitely seems relevant, though I am struggling a bit to distill the thread down to what I should do in this particular situation.  The thread eventually references forthcoming `@Subcomponent` support as a better solution, though; I see `@Subcomponent` now exists, though the documentation is sparse, so it would be great if someone could comment on that.

Answer (score 3):

You usually mark the *top* component as `@Singleton` and then all the subcomponents and `provide*()` that need it. After all, singleton can be guaranteed only on global graph level.

Starting to mark with `@Singleton` from bottom will lead to multiple errors (as you experienced) until you get to the very top. So probably it will be easier to rollback and start from the top `@Component`